# resolve path issue, js file not connecting

Tags: javascript, html, parceljs

I have just started with a parcel projekt, and I am having trouble to resolve a path issue.

This is my directory structure:

```
root
  |__src
      |__js
      |  |__lib
      |  |   |__bro.js
      |  |_index.js
      |
      |__styles
      |    |_main.scss
      |__index.html
      |__index.js
      |__bro.js
```

If I connect my html file to the index.js when its in the same level as the html file it works out fine with the following in my html file:

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

and in the index.js file I connect to bro.js and main.scss with the following code:

```
import {bro} from './bro'
import './styles/main.scss'

document.querySelector('h1').textContent = bro(`How is it going`)
```

The code for bro.js is the following:

```
const bro = (greetings) => {
    return `${greetings}, bro`
}

export {bro}
```

This is working fine and will put out following on the html page:

> How is it going, bro

What I would like to solve is if I move index.js file in the js folder, and bro.js file in the lib folder within the js folder.

I have tried the following in the html file if index.js is in the js folder:

```
<script src="./js/index.js"></script>
```

and in the index.js file when its in the js folder change the following to connect to bro in the lib folder which is in the js folder, and main.scss which is in the styles folder:

```
import {bro} from './lib/bro'
import '../styles/main.scss'


document.querySelector('h3').textContent = bro(`How is it going`)
```

The output I am getting is the static h3 content:

> My Page

The main.scss in the styles folder is working, but I am not getting the proper output of the bro.js file in the lib folder.

What am i missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some research and the imports are fine as you have them. here is the code I've done to simulate your problem.

[image: index.html]
[image: index.js]
[image: bro.js]

And here are the executions, stoping in the queryselector and after it. So I'm guessing the issue is the DOM is not yet loaded when you are using the querySelector (I was getting an error of trying to .textContent of null.

Because with the updated folder tree you've given, the imports are just fine.

[image: Stopped in the querySelector]
[image: After running the code]

And if I remove the window.onload this is the behaviour

[image: console error without waiting for DOM]

and the code in index.js (the only thing that changed) is

```
import { bro } from './lib/bro'
document.querySelector('#myid').textContent = bro(`How is it going`)
```

Comment: Sorry, I messed up my diagram, the index.html is in the src folder, and I want to move the index.js file in the js folder which is in the src folder, and the bro.js folder in the lib folder within js folder, within js folder.

Comment: And can you please explain if the failed import is the index.js or bro.js?

Comment: I am not getting any errors if I use <script src="index.js"></script> in my html code, and then in index.js if its in the js folder, and I use: import {bro} from './lib/bro' if bro.js is in the lib folder in js folder, the js code in bro.js is never executed, I just get the static content of the h3 tag. No error is generated though. and the code: import '../styles/main.scss' is able to connect to main.scss file in styles folder

Comment: and with that you don't get an error when trying to querySelector an element not yet loaded in the DOM? I've done a test and with that imports works fine but waiting for the dom to be loaded

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, but I am still getting the static value :( I have created a git repo, can I add you on that repo if I could write directly to your stackoverflow account?

Comment: Hey, I solved it somehow without the window.onload method.. with the following:

import {bro} from './lib/bro'
import '../styles/main.scss'


document.querySelector('h1').textContent = bro(`How is it going`)

Comment: Actually, your suggestion working with a id instead of a tag seems more scalable, but I still didn't need to window.onload, I changed to the following:

document.getElementById('myID').textContent = bro(`How is it going`)

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Thanks for accepting the answer. And for sure you can add me on GitHub. A pleasure, partner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189864/discussion-between-user2371684-and-samus24).